# Remove Stop Words - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am reading in a csv file and then getting all the words in the file. What I am trying to then do is remove all stop words using nltk. I am very new to Python so excuse me if this is a bad question. 
Here is my code

```
    import pandas as pd
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords

def loadCsv(fileName):
    df = pd.read_csv(fileName, error_bad_lines=False)
    df.dropna(inplace = True)
    return df

def getWords(dataframe):
    words = []
    for tweet in dataframe['SentimentText'].tolist():
        for word in tweet.split():
            word = word.lower()

        words.append(word)

    return set(words) #Create a set from the words list

def removeStopWords(words):
    filtered_word_list = words[:] #make a copy of the word_list
    for word in words: # iterate over word_list
        if word in stopwords.words('english'): 
            filtered_word_list.remove(word) # remove word from filtered_word_list if it is a stopword

    return set(filtered_word_list)

df = loadCsv("train.csv")
words = getWords(df)
words = removeStopWords(words)
```

I am getting the following error.

> 'set' object is not subscriptable

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: Can you include the full traceback error? This will mean we can see the line on which error occurs.

Comment: Rather than copying the words "list", you can use a list comprehension to create a new list.

Comment: Your most recent edit messed up the indentation of your code.

Comment: I suggest you read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for debugging tips

Answer (score 2):

You made `words` a set, so it's not a list and `words[:]` is non-sense.

Try this instead `return list(set(words))`

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to structure all the code in user defined functions, I am not sure if there is a reason behind it but the problem is very simple and can be succinctly worked out in practically 2 lines of code, after reading your datafrme.

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
```

create the stop_words list

```
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
stop_words[:10]
```

output

```
['i', 'me', 'my', 'myself', 'we', 'our', 'ours', 'ourselves', 'you', "you're"]
```

I am going to demonstrate using the first few lines in a poem by John Keats, this is a .txt file which i read into a dataframe.

```
df = pd.read_table('keats.txt', error_bad_lines = False, header = -1 , names = ['poem'], na_filter= True)
df
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

add a new column to df call it *cleaned* where every row is lowercase and split by space
**this is effectively your first step in processing**
you can do this using either
**1) lambda operator**

```
df['cleaned'] = list(map(lambda x: x.lower().split(), df.poem))
```

or **2) listcomp**

```
df['cleaned'] = [x.lower().split() for x in df.poem]
```

[image]

the second and final step is filtering stop words, the easiest way is using a map combined with a filter.
add this as a third column to your df:

```
df['filtered'] = list(map(lambda line: list(filter(lambda word: word not in stop_words, line)), df.cleaned))
df
```

[image]

so effectively, as I mentioned earlier you only need two lines of code to process your dataframe.
.
.
.
there is a little bit to unpack in this last step, let's take the first row in column df.cleaned

```
df.cleaned[0]
```

output

```
['deep', 'in', 'the', 'shady', 'sadness', 'of', 'a', 'vale']
```

what `map(filter(lambda x: according to condition, data_source))` does is filter the words that are not in stop words

```
list(filter(lambda word: word not in stop_words, df.cleaned[0]))
```

output

```
['deep', 'shady', 'sadness', 'vale']
```

this filter statement acts as a function that you can pass into a `map(function, column)`
where the filter is the function argument and the column is the column `df.cleaned`
As such the filtration (system) if you will is applied to each row iteratively and the results are posted in the new column. 
if you look closely you can see that the skeleton of the map/filter statement is as follows:

map(lambda: *line*, filter(lambda word: word not in stop_words, *line*), source_of_*line*)

notice how line is extracted from every row in the dataframe then passed into the filter expression where the words in that line are filtered.

hope I've done a good job clarifying this. 
.
.
.

since you're new to python allow me to share a few thoughts 
1- python is an elegant language written with the purpose of brevity and readability. The clunciest thing one can do is write explicit for loops, unless necessary for loops are almost always replaceable with listcomps or generator expressions. same goes for user defined functions.

2- there's is a lot it code out there that is inherited from 2.7, such as `words[:]` for instance, you don't need the `[:]` bit anymore.

3- try to understand the attributes of containers, containers in python are things like *list*, *tuple*, *set*, *dict*. The error that you're getting above with the set is usually returned when you try to slice your set, by slice I mean subset, take portion of. if you have a set, call is `set_1` and you do `set_1[:10]` you get `set object not subscriptabl`. that's because sets are non-sequenced containers in python, meaning elements of a set have no index assigned to them, so you cannot sort or subset sets or call the first, second or Nth element like you do with lists. One can display instance methods and attributed of an object by using `dir(object)`

4- never stop tinkering with code

Answer (score 0):

The return of your function `getWords` is a `set` object, which is then passed as parameter to function `removeStopWords`, and in it's first statement you try to access the values with fancy indexing operation:

```
filtered_word_list = words[:]
```

What you need to do is cast the set to a list just before return it from the `getWords` method:

```
return list(set(words)) #Create a set from the words list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filtered_word_list = words[:] #make a copy of the word_list
```

Here `words` is a set, not a list, so this line throws an error. You can use a list comprehension to create the list of non-stop words:

```
return [x for x in words if x not in stopwords.words('english')]
```

This avoids the need to make a copy and doesn't require `words` to be a list.

Comment: I tried this and I still get the exception: no description error. Apologies by the way I'm very new and reading a lot of different things

Comment: @JohnOC Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post a new question with the current code. When you edit your question, the answers no longer make any sense to future visitors.